# How to call instagram images in wordpress theme without using plugin

Tags: wordpress

I need to call Instagram feed in WordPress theme without using the plugin. is their anyone to help me with this problem. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Instafeed.js script to get Instagram images - http://instafeedjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use plugin to load Instagram feeds, then you are supposed to use [Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) or you may use a ready open source library like [this](https://github.com/pgrimaud/instagram-user-feed).